# Closing connection, but not display message

Tags: node.js

I have the following code and it works, but not display message 'too big file'. I see a chrome screen with `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. How can I close the connection and display the message?

```
var size = 0;

var gotData = function(d) {
    size += d.length;
    if (size > (1 * 1024 * 1024)) {
          console.log('aborting request');
          res.writeHead(413, {
              'Connection': 'close'
          });
          res.end('too big file');
    }
};

req.on('data', gotData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

```
var size = 0;

var sizeTooMuch = function(){
      console.log('aborting request');
      response.writeHead(413, 'Request Entity Too Large', {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      response.end('<!doctype html><html><head><title>413</title></head><body>Too big file 413</body></html>')          
      return false;
}

var gotData = function(d) {
    size += d.length;
    if(size > (1 * 1024 * 1024){
    sizeTooMuch();
   }
};

var endFunc = function(){
      console.log("got the file");
      res.send("got the file");
      res.end();
}

req.on('data', gotData);

req.on('end', endFunc);
```

Comment: Thanks, This works, but the server will load entire upload.I would like to abort and display the message.

Comment: The connection closes, but I see ERR_CONNECTION_RESET of chrome page. The message 'too big file' doesn't displayed.

Comment: try this again please @MarioLopes

Comment: result? @MarioLopes

Comment: I added res.connection.destroy(); for not upload all file and close the connection. It works. I saw that my chrome version display this error page. new versions display the html. Thanks @Ahmet, I will close the problem. Thanks a lot